# How to read HFS+ extended attributes under Linux

Tags: linux, attributes, hfs+

I have successfully mounted HFS+ volume under Linux, but when I try to read HFS+ extended security attribute on the file I get the error "Operation not supported":

```
[root@localhost hfsvol]# getfattr --name="com.apple.system.cprotect" file.db
file.db: com.apple.system.cprotect: Operation not supported
[root@localhost hfsvol]#
```

Why this happens? I know that the file 'file.db' exactly has the attribute "com.apple.system.cprotect".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)